# Using raspberry pi to connect to OPC server

Tags: raspberry-pi, server, ole, opc, process-control

I'm pretty new to working with servers/clients and all that, which is why I'm having trouble communicating to a server with my Raspberry Pi.

Basically, I have an OLE Process Control (OPC) server and client with a bunch of tags on it that have information. What I am trying to do is find/write OPC source code that can search my server for those tags and then do stuff with them. Matrikon has a really good tutorial http://openopc.sourceforge.net/api.html that uses OpenOPC as its source code with pre-written functions and a simulation server. But when I use a real server (National Instruments OPC server), I am lost as to whether I can reuse the OpenOPC source code or if I need something else.

My instincts tell me that I am completely off track, so it would really help if someone else has dealt with this before and could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Is your server an OPC-DA or OPC-UA server?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, **OPC DA** is designed based on Windows OS.

Therefore, Raspberry Pi does not support **OPC DA**, because it is based on Linux OS.

If you have no choice but with Raspberry Pi and **OPC DA**, you should find an OPC Server, support both of **OPC DA** and **OPC UA**.

**OPC UA** was developed after **OPC DA**, and is designed to be OS-independent.

So, **OPC UA** will work on Raspberry Pi maybe...

If configure it as below, you will probably be able to use **OPC DA** communication with Raspberry Pi via OPC Server.

Raspberry Pi <-- (**OPC UA**) --> **OPC UA** / **OPC DA** Server <-- (**OPC DA**) --> Application

May the code be with you.

Answer (score 0):

OPC is a defined interface between a client and server application. Of course, there are always a few gotchas but by-and-large, client code that works with one server should work with any server.